# Convert array(double) to varchar in Presto

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I'm trying to convert Array(double) to varchar in Presto.
A sample value:
[99.0,98.0,99.0,95.0,99.0,88.0,90.0,79.0,90.0,56.0,90.0,90.0,92.0,90.0,93.0,99.0]

I tried the cast function below:

`cast(colname as varchar)`

But got this error message: *"Cannot cast array(double) to varchar"*

Any ideas how to convert this array to varchar.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`array_join`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_join):

> `array_join(x, delimiter, null_replacement)` → `varchar`
>
> Concatenates the elements of the given array using the delimiter and an optional string to replace nulls.

```
SELECT array_join(ARRAY [1, 2],  ', ') -- 1, 2
```

Or cast to json and use [`json_format`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_format):

```
SELECT json_format(cast(ARRAY [1, 2] as json)) -- [1,2]
```

Comment: @ali60vip was glad to help!