# In Trino (Presto) SQL, how do you convert an array of characters (char) into a varchar (string)?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I want to take an array of characters, for example, `['t','e','s','t','']` and turn it into a string; in this case 'test'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert array(double) to varchar in Presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681032/convert-arraydouble-to-varchar-in-presto)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do this: use `ARRAY_JOIN` with a blank string:

`SELECT ARRAY_JOIN(ARRAY ['t','e','s','t',''], '') as new_string;`

| # | new_string |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |