# Trying to convert json to string (Athena AWS)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a json formatted like:
`myjson = {"key":["value1","value2"]}` and a I want to convert it as string
Sometime this json can return null:
`myjson = {"key":null}`
.

I want to get the values as a string, but I get an error when I try to cast `cast(json_extract(myjson,'$.key') as varchar)`.
The error says that is not possible to convert '["value1","value2"]' to varchar. I think it is because of the double quote. I need help to work around this problem.

Edit1:

- The output of json_extract(myjson,'$.key') is a json object;
- I want to get a string like 'value1, value2' or 'null'
- At the moment I do not know how to verify if it is null or not

Comment: What you say "I want to convert it as string", what does your desired output string look like?

Comment: I want to create a list of strings ' value1,value2,value3,...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`json_format`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.285/functions/json.html#json_format) (though depending on the following usage leaving just `json_extract` without cast/format/etc. can be fine in some cases):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(json_str) as (
    values ('{"key":["value1","value2"]}'),
        ('{"key":null}')
)

-- query
select json_format(json_extract(json_str,'$.key'))
from dataset;
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| ["value1","value2"] |
| null |

Another option is casting the result of `json_extract` to `array(varchar)` and using `array_join` on it (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66681137/2501279) for example).

Comment: Broken link: the link "json_format" goes to a Presto page which does not have any information about "json_format".

Comment: @Tony thank you, fixed. It seems that they have removed "current" version which was used in the link

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution

```
cast(json_extract(json_str, '$.key') as array(varchar)) as array_values
array_join(array_values,',' )
```

With this a get a string like `'value1,value2'` it is easier to work then `'["value1","value2"]'`

Answer (score 0):

You can not cast list to string, but if you want you can join list items to string like.

```sql
array_join(json_extract(myjson,'$.key'), ' ')
```

Comment: I tried this and I got the following error 
'Unexpected parameters (json, varchar(1)) for function array_join. Expected: array_join(array(T), varchar) T, array_join(array(T), varchar, varchar) T'